# How to zip files without the top level folder but keep the sub folders

Tags: bash, shell, unix, zip

Suppose I have a folder named abc, it has several sub folders recursively, I want to zip everything under abc, when I use the following command

```
zip -r abc.zip abc/*
```

I get abc.zip, but it contains the top level folder abc, and everything is under abc, like abc/xxx, abc/yyy etc, How can I remove the top level folder abc? I want to put everything directly in abc.zip.

Note:

1. I can only zip from outside of the folder, so navigate to folder abc, and zip * is not work for me
2. I need to run this command in a single line, I can separated multiple commands by ;
3. option -j also does not work, since it remove the sub folders, I want to keep them there.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
cd abc
zip -r ../abc.zip *
```

Though I will say in most cases keeping it abc makes for easier management.

Answer (score 6):

`7z a -tzip abc.zip -w abc/.`

321

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20545864/266531) from [reiso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333536/reisio), you could use the [7-Zip utility](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z) which has an option to pass a working directory to the zip process. This is like changing to that directory before running the `zip` command.

```
7z a -tzip abc.zip -w abc/.
```

The `a` is for add files. The `-w abc/.` sets the working directory to the folder `abc`, which will exclude the `/abc/` path from the path of all the folders and files in your zip.

I was able to install the 7-Zip utility by running `brew install p7zip`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I faced with the same issue. For me the following was working fine in bash:

```
$ ABC_HOME="..../abc"
$ cp abc.zip "$ABC_HOME"

$ cd "$ABC_HOME"
$ unzip abc.zip -d ../
```

> **[-d exdir]**
>
> An optional directory to which to extract files. By
> default, all files and subdirectories are recreated in the current
> directory; the -d option allows extraction in an arbitrary directory
> (always assuming one has permission to write to the directory). This
> option need not appear at the end of the command line; it is also
> accepted before the zipfile specification (with the normal options),
> immediately after the zipfile specification, or between the file(s)
> and the -x option. The option and directory may be concatenated
> without any white space between them, but note that this may cause
> normal shell behavior to be suppressed. In particular, ''-d ~''
> (tilde) is expanded by Unix C shells into the name of the user's home
> directory, but ''-d~'' is treated as a literal subdirectory ''~'' of
> the current directory.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip