# Create zip folder without top level, but keep subfolders

Tags: linux, macos, zip

**Note** it looks like there are pre-existing questions that are similar, but the solutions to those answers have not worked for me. See: [How to zip files without the top level folder but keep the sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719408/how-to-zip-files-without-the-top-level-folder-but-keep-the-sub-folders)

I have this folder structure:

```
index.js
node_modules/some_module
```

If I zip these with just `-r`:

```sh
zip -r bundle.zip *
```

Then I will get something like:

```
bundle/
  index.js
  some_file_from_module.js
  another_file_from_module.js
...
```

Everything will be inside of a `/bundle` folder.

I can remove the bundle folder with `-j`

```sh
zip -jr bundle.zip *
```

But then all of my subfolders are removed:

```sh
index.js
some_file_from_module.js
another_file_From_module.js
...
```

Is there a way I can retain the folder structure I want without having the top level `bundle` folder after unzipping the zip?

Comment: I have also tried `-u` to "update" the zip and `-g` to "grow" the zip with a secondary `zip` command after first creating the zip folder using `zip -jr`. This ended up adding the `bundle` top level directory back to the zip.

Comment: You didn't say what your current folder is, `pwd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is:

```
cd bundle
zip -r ../bundle.zip *
cd ..
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182036/101265